# Next.js build error when generating static pages during docker image build

Tags: docker, next.js, dockerfile

Windows
react@18.10
next@12.1.6

I am in the process of finalizing a Next.js migration and I am being faced with a localhost docker build issue. The site makes use of `getStaticProps` and therefore generates the html during build time. There is a locally hosted headless cms at `http://localhost:7071` that the site makes use of to maintain the page information.

When the site is built when not making use of docker it works fine and the static content is generated; however, when when building a docker image, the connection to the cms is refused.

I know it has to do with the docker build process not being able to access the headless cms, but I have exhausted my knowledge in finding out how to get the build process to access the localhost.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine as dependencies

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

FROM node:18-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

# Package files
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

# Files required for next
COPY next-env.d.ts .
COPY next-sitemap.config.js .
COPY next.config.redirects.js .
COPY next.config.rewrites.js .
COPY next.config.js .

# Linter
COPY .eslintrc.json .

# Environment loader
COPY loadAppEnv.js .

# Program files
COPY src/ ./src/
COPY pages/ ./pages/
COPY public/ ./public/
COPY environments/ ./environments/

COPY --from=dependencies /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN npm run build:local
RUN npm run sitemap

FROM node:18-alpine as runner

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.redirects.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.rewrites.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/loadAppEnv.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/sshd_config /etc/ssh/

# Install and configure SSH
RUN apk add openssh \
    && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd

# Configure running
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:local"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      network: "host"
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    network_mode: "host"
```

Error I am getting:

```
#26 21.25 info  - Collecting page data...
#26 21.75 (node:80) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
#26 21.75 (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
#26 21.77
#26 21.77 > Build error occurred
#26 21.77 TypeError: fetch failed
#26 21.77     at Object.processResponse (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5555:34)
#26 21.77     at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5877:42
#26 21.77     at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
#26 21.77     at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
#26 21.77     at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
#26 21.77     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
#26 21.77   type: 'TypeError',
#26 21.77   cause: {
#26 21.77     errno: -111,
#26 21.77     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
#26 21.77     syscall: 'connect',
#26 21.77     address: '127.0.0.1',
#26 21.77     port: 7071
#26 21.77   }
#26 21.77 }
```

Comment: In a container, including a build container, `localhost` is the container itself. You need to put the address of the host machine. I'm honestly not sure how you do that. You might try using `host.docker.internal` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I was doing exactly that but in the wrong place. You are amazing! It is working now perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Hans Kilian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72734047/next-js-build-error-when-generating-static-pages-during-docker-image-build?noredirect=1#comment128473215_72734047), I needed to change the reference url to the api from `http://localhost:7071` to `http://host.docker.internal:7071`.